# Why does libc++'s implementation of shared_ptr use full memory barriers instead of relaxed?

Tags: c++, boost, thread-safety, shared-ptr, libc++

In boost's implementation of `shared_ptr`, it uses [relaxed memory ordering to increment its reference count](https://github.com/boostorg/smart_ptr/blob/master/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_clang.hpp#L29). This appears safe as decrements use acquire/release to make sure that any previous decrements are visible to the thread before releasing memory. This method seems correct and appears in Herb Sutters [talk on atomics](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2)

In libc++'s implementation uses [full memory barriers](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/memory.cpp)

```
template <class T>
inline T
increment(T& t) _NOEXCEPT
{
    return __sync_add_and_fetch(&t, 1);
}

template <class T>
inline T
decrement(T& t) _NOEXCEPT
{
    return __sync_add_and_fetch(&t, -1);
}

}  // name
```

Is there a reason for this decision? Are there any performance or safety differences between them?

Comment: According to [implementation details here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), it says "To satisfy thread safety requirements, the reference counters are typically incremented and decremented using an equivalent of std::atomic::fetch_add with std::memory_order_relaxed."  I was hoping to find source for it to confirm the statement, but I am having trouble finding online documentation of the libc++ source code for gcc (albeit they are only naive Google searches, maybe someone can provide a link).  I notice your link is for LLVM though.

Comment: Who wrote that code, when, why and what else did they write ... if only there was a way find out. ;)

Comment: @Aggieboy I think the mirror I linked is the source for libc++ on GCC as well, you just compile it with `-gcc-toolchain`. libstd++ (default standard library on GCC) uses `__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add`, which I believe is also a full barrier but I'm not sure. It seems like it's commonish knowledge that it should be implemented with relaxed barriers but I can't seem to find any library besides boost that does it

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'd settle for some decent comments :P. I'm just curious why any STL implementation would go against best practice for thread safe reference counting (for performance) when it obviously has the ability to use it (atomics are there, just use them!). Maybe it was just how they did it, but maybe someone more familiar with atomics can shed some light on whether not there is a good reason to do it this way

Comment: Just to not leave any bad vibes here, @ChrisT, I wanted to (ironically) suggest that you check the according version control system. That's what the "blame" or "annotate" commands can be used for in many such systems. I'm not  sure if this irony came across though...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Because when I wrote that code, the compiler (clang) had not yet implemented C++11 atomics.  And I never got back to it to clean it up.

Nothing subtle here. :-)

Comment: Finally, an answer relating to atomics that I understand!

Comment: Hah, I just got a "You did't pass" when this answer was shown to "audit" my reviews... I had flagged this as spam, thinking that someone with no rep (it wasn't showing the _real_ user) was extremely unlikely to have written code, let alone an entire library, that someone else was now asking about :-D

Comment: At first look, I thought this was a bad self-answer (the smiley in particular).  I was on guard for audits, so I passed, but it's not a great audit choice.

Comment: For future visitors to this page, it looks like this was fixed: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22803