# Why does std::shared_ptr::use_count() use relaxed_memory_order instead of full memory barrier?

Tags: c++

Please note this is not the same question as [Why does libc++'s implementation of shared_ptr use full memory barriers instead of relaxed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199212/why-does-libcs-implementation-of-shared-ptr-use-full-memory-barriers-instead)
.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count) says

> In multithreaded environment, the value returned by use_count is approximate (typical implementations use a memory_order_relaxed load).

But why do implementations choose to not use memory barrier? Because it is a burden on performance, or (what?!!) technically not feasible?

Comment: "technically not feasible?" Huh? You can always put a memory fence anywhere in the code yourself. Just why put a memory barrier if it is unneeded?

Comment: What would be the benefit? We can't rely on the return value in actual production code anyway. So what would be the benefit of a memory barrier? The primary utility of `use_count` is usually in a debugging session.

Comment: “What would be the benefit?” This post is not advocating for using or not using memory barrier, only trade-off. How about this: what’s the benefit of *not* doing so?

Comment: @Leedehai: Why would you use a thing to achieve some effect when you could achieve the same effect by *not* using the thing?

Comment: I don’t intend to use it. One doesn’t have to use a thing to ask questions about it.